# Injection into Razor Component -Development Working, Production Not

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor, asp.net-core-6.0

Hopefully, this is just a stupid question, since I'm new at Blazor.

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application running at our company, and I want to introduce Blazor to it. Everything has been working fine, until I try to do an injection into a Razor component.

This injection contains all our database connections and what not. It works perfectly fine when injecting into a cshtml page, AND it works perfectly fine, when I run the Razor component locally via my Visual Studio.

However, when I publish and upload to our server, I get this error:

[image: Error]

The error is occurring when I simply attempt to use the injection command, before even using it:

[image: Injection Command]

What's weird is, it's referencing the folder structure on MY computer (`C:\Web Sites...`) NOT the server's, even though it's sitting on the server.

I have no idea how to proceed, since, again, the exact same injection works on cshtml pages AND when I run the site on my computer via Visual Studio.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: The error is in the constructor of your implementation - you are missing dependencies that it requires (I notice `IHttpContextAccessor` and `IActionContextAccessor` which should not be used in Blazor). Are you trimming/using AOT when you publish? That can cause differences between "on my machine" and on the server.

Comment: Does it works in local project? Could you please try create a new project and then try to publish that in your prod, if that performs well, then please share your exiting one configuration with us.

Comment: I will have to check with the other programmer to see if he switched it to AOT. Thanks for that lead!

Comment: It works in the local project without n issue. However, since our project is very big and too complicated, it's impossible to recreate something similar from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have in the Implementation of the ItransporterPackage also an injection of a Objekt that ist not initialize in Produktion Environment.

Ist the Interface and Implementation registert in the Blazire Programm.cs?

Comment: The Transporter package is registered in Startup.cs and that's why it's working everywhere else in the program. Do I have to register it separately for Blazor?

Comment: Oh yes, you build a blazor webassembly application with a asp.net backend? So you have two program.cs, one for the backend and one for the blazor frontend. The Services in Blazor just registered in the program.cs of the fronend project.

Comment: I believe I'm doing it as a server not a webassembly.

Comment: And I'm running:
services.AddServerSideBlazor(o => o.DetailedErrors = true);
in Startup.cs (that's why Blazor is working in the first place)